# Is using the internet for your answer valid?

Tags: discussion

If I write out the answer to a problem and put it on GitHub, then I can easily win a challenge by simply writing code to fetch the answer. Is this valid? I've never seen it been forbidden in a challenge's rules.

Comment: [Fetching output from external sources](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1062/12914) is one of the standard loopholes.

Comment: The reason you've never seen it forbidden in a challenge's rules is because it's seen as a *standard loophole*, e.g. loopholes which may be assumed to be closed without the question-setter having to explicitly close them. This particular loophole is listen on [our page of standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1062/31716) as the second highest answer.